# Antiforgery tokens for multiple ajax json requests

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I implemented the following code in my MVC application to load some Json objects when a user clicks on a link.

```
<form>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
</form>

$("body").on('click', ".clickhere", (function () {
var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/do/things',
        cache: false,
        headers: { "__RequestVerificationToken": token },
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: data
 },
        success: function () {
            ...
        },
        error: function () {
            ...
        }
   });  
});
```

and I verify the token according to [this tutorial](http://richiban.uk/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/). The strange fact is that this is working if I run the project from within Visual Studio 2015, but not if it is published as a application on IIS 6.2. When running on IIS I can clearly see that the request tokens do not match.

Comment: could be seeing cached page with stale token. What happens with a hard refresh?

Comment: @charlietfl same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work I changed the code in the view to:

```
 @functions{
    public string GetAntiForgeryToken()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + "," + formToken;
    }
 }
<input type="hidden" name="__RequestVerificationToken" id="__RequestVerificationToken" value="@GetAntiForgeryToken()" />
```